# What is the symbol for Matrix inverse operator?

Tags: matrix, symbolic, symbols

I tried to take inverse of a matrix A using Inverse[A] and it gave me the right result. But when I tried using notation form A<sup>-1</sup> by using typesetting superscript, it gives me wrong result (element wise inverse of matrix, see figure below). Is it possible to get inverse of a matrix using symbolic form? if so, how to get inverse of a matrix using symbolic input form? (Since A<sup>T</sup> symbol works for Transpose of a matrix). Thank you in advance
[image: Inverse of Matrix A]

Comment: If there were any, then the doc page would mention it. So I guess, there is no way to input the inverse symbolically.

Comment: Apparently, exponentiation of a matrix just distributes over the elements. I haven't encountered that elsewhere.

Comment: You can select `Inverse[A]` and `Cell->Convert To->TraditionalForm` it, where it does look like $A^{-1}$.

Comment: @DavidKeith that's standard for numerical programs, e.g. `numpy`. If you want a power you use `MatrixPower`.

Comment: @swish Thank you for the tip.

Comment: And if you want Matrix exponentiation, use MatrixExp.

Comment: Thanks, @b3m2a1. That is good to know.